# How can I embed Ruby shell (or pry) emulator into a website?

Tags: ruby, irb, pry, terminal-emulator

I'd like to add Ruby shell (irb) or pry emulator into a website like [Try Ruby](http://tryruby.org). How can I do it?

EDIT: TryRuby was created with jquery-console as I understood from its source code but I wonder another way (especially in Ruby, otherwise JavaScript) to do it.

ANOTHER EDIT: I've voted to close my own question as;

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

I won't delete it and I will be very proud to ask questions forever!

Comment: This is not a kind of question suitable for SO.

Comment: @mudasobwa I wonder the reason why it is not suitable for here.

Comment: @ekremkaraca: it looks very much like gem/tool recommendation request.

Comment: Don't worry, the community will delete it for you (if it deems this necessary). And if you ask too many bad questions, you'll find yourself question-banned rather quickly.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm waiting for more close votes to be closed/deleted. I won't fill here with bad questions but I expect to be shown a place to find an answer to questions/recommendations like this question.

Comment: I think your last edit is more suitable as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all a trivial task.

---

One approach would be to have the browser send requests to the server. The downsides are - you need to manage the server, you have to implement the front end communication with the server, etc. normal webapp stuff. The biggest problem - there is no functional sandbox for cRuby out there. If you need any degree of security measures - you have to implement them on your own.

A place for inspiration - the rails browser console for development mode.

---

Another approach is to use [Opal](http://opalrb.com/) and keep everything on the user side. The huge issue there - while it tries to, Opal is not an exact implementation of the language (it being defined by the cRuby implementation). So if complete *"realism"* is something that you need - this solution is not applicable.

A place for inspiration - the opal site itself has a section that lets you try out Ruby code in the browser.